# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception vuejs and cordova

Tags: cordova, vuejs2

I created a new project and haven't added anything to the starter code and whenever I run npm run cordova-build-android, I get this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Tutorial link : https://medium.com/@acejon96/building-an-android-app-with-vue-js-fc0aefb454d9

```
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: C:\xampp\htdocs\my-app\App\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b C:\xampp\htdocs\my-app\App\platforms\android\build.gradle


package.jon

  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

android/build.gradle.js

```
allprojects {
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="29.0.2" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=22 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 5.1
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=29 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}
```

I have latest version of android studio (arctic fox)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to uninstall and install Android SDK Build Tools. In your Android Studio, open Android SDK, SDK Tools tab. Find Android SDK Build Tools version 31.0.0 and uninstall it. Then try to install it again.
2. Somehow, Android SDK Build Tools version 31.0.0 is missing some files, especially `dx.bat` and `dx.jar`. We need to fix this.

Steps to fix:

1. Go to Android SDK Build Tools 31.0.0 folder. For example

   ```
   "~\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0"
   ```
2. Find a file named `d8.bat`.
3. Create a copy of `d8.bat` and rename it to `dx.bat`.
4. In the `lib` folder, find `d8.jar`.
5. Create a copy of `d8.jar` and rename it to `dx.jar`.

Comment: I have already tried.But Issue not fixed.

Comment: Hi, I've added more solution. You can try it

Comment: Thank you. I think mentioned folder is placed in C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Android . i am right..? In my computer i can't find a folder which Appdata.  I have seen only a .android folder. In program files there is a android folder ,that folder contain android studio. i am a noob in android. I have previous experience only in php .

Comment: Mostly AppData is a hidden folder. Try to show hidden folder in your File Explorer.